# How can I further improve this database model?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, visio

I'm looking to further improve my database design from my other post - [How can I improve this database model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883606/how-can-i-improve-this-database-model)

I've implemented ideas from the answer into my own design and have been fixing it up a bit. I just need to check if you guys agree with my database model and if not could you let me know how I can improve it, especially with the relationships between tables (one to one, many to many)?

On transaction Detail table - transactiontype would equate to sales or rental

Table dvd should remain dvd as its apart of the business logic.

Comment: Looks fine... not really sure what your looking to optimize here.

Comment: @bnjmn Well I'm new to this any I'm just trying to make sure that I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the price of a DVD ever change? If so, does it matter that the history will change as well? What if it changes between order and payment (if applicable)?

Comment: So should I have another table to store the historical prices of dvd for a certain period of time? I'm pretty sure I don't need to worry about this as its just an assignment but we are allowed to introduce new business rules. So that's defiantly something I will look into thanks. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Say someone orders DVD A twice for sale (one for a friend of course) and DVD B for themselves, so that's 3 DVD's total. How would you store that currently?

Comment: Also, you have modelled the concept of 'address' twice. Wouldn't it be easier to have a generic address table and have transaction relate to it in a 'BillingAddress' sense and have Customer relate to it in a regular address sense?

Comment: The dvds would be stored in transactiondetail table. Thanks for the address idea too.

Comment: Then what is TransactionQuantity for ;)

Comment: Ahh, yes didn't delete that when rearranging my tables. I'll delete that now. Thanks